# How to Parallelize Backtracking Algorithm using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm

I wrote a sudoku solver program implementing a backtracking algorithm. The code works well iteratively but I want to make it parallel using threads and not open mp. After a deep analysis I know I have to change the logic of my implementation but I can't understand how can I parallelize a complete search algorithm and how to make the threads not repeat the same work as other threads. Can someone help me? here is my code.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


void printSudoku9x9(int sudoku[9][9]) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            cout << sudoku[y][x] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

}

bool canPlace9x9(int sudoku[9][9], int row, int col, int n)
{
    if (sudoku[row][col] != 0) return false;
    bool status = true;
    int gridx = (col / 3) * 3;
    int gridy = (row / 3) * 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (sudoku[row][i] == n) { status = false; break; }
        if (sudoku[i][col] == n) { status = false; break; }
        if (sudoku[gridy + i / 3][gridx + i % 3] == n) { status = false; break; }
    }
    return status;
}

void nextEmpty(int sudoku[9][9], int row, int col, int& rowNext, int& colNext)
{

    int indexNext = 9 * 9 + 1;
    for (int i = row * 9 + col + 1; i < 9 * 9; i++) {
        if (sudoku[i / 9][i % 9] == 0) {

            indexNext = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    rowNext = indexNext / 9;
    colNext = indexNext % 9;
}

void copyArray(int sudoku[9][9], int sudokuCopy[9][9]) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            sudokuCopy[y][x] = sudoku[y][x];
}
std::vector<int> findPlaceables(int sudoku[9][9], int row, int col) {
    vector<int> placebles = {};
    for (int n = 1; n <= 9; n++)
        if (canPlace9x9(sudoku, row, col, n)) placebles.push_back(n);
    return placebles;
}


bool solveSudoku9x9(int sudoku[9][9], int row, int col)
{
    if (row > 8) return true;
    if (sudoku[row][col] != 0) {
        int rowNext, colNext;
        nextEmpty(sudoku, row, col, rowNext, colNext);
        return solveSudoku9x9(sudoku, rowNext, colNext);
    }

    std::vector<int> placebles = findPlaceables(sudoku, row, col);

    if (placebles.size() == 0) {
        
        return false;
    
    };

    bool status = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < placebles.size(); i++) {
        int n = placebles[i];
        int sudokuCopy[9][9];
        copyArray(sudoku, sudokuCopy);
        //cout << "(" << row << "," << col << ") =>" << n << endl;
        sudokuCopy[row][col] = n;
        int rowNext = row;
        int colNext = col;
        nextEmpty(sudokuCopy, row, col, rowNext, colNext);
        if (solveSudoku9x9(sudokuCopy, rowNext, colNext)) {
            copyArray(sudokuCopy, sudoku);
            status = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return status;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int board[9][9] = {
        {5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0},
        {6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0},
        {0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0},
        {8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3},
        {4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1},
        {7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6},
        {0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0},
        {0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5},
        {0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9}
    };
    int board2[9][9] = {
        {8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,7,0,0,9,0,2,0,0},
        {0,5,0,0,0,7,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,4,5,7,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,6,8},
        {0,0,8,5,0,0,0,1,0},
        {0,9,0,0,0,0,4,0,0}
    };
    
    if (solveSudoku9x9(board, 0, 0)) cout << "successfully solved board!" << std::endl;
    printSudoku9x9(board);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While not a multi-threaded solution, you are welcome to peruse the source to my Sudoku solver [on Github](https://github.com/jselbie/SudokuSolver).  It solves your first `board` matrix in a few milliseconds.  Your `board2` has too many open spaces to be solved algorithmically and probably does not have a unique solution - so it can only be solved by brute force and multiple solutions exist.  Newspapers typically don't publish sudoku boards that require backtracking or guessing.

Comment: I don't know why someone is voting to close, the question is already sufficiently focused and answerable.

Comment: To do something like this multi-threaded, you have to make some concession upfront to accommodate multi-threading.   In your case, the easiest way to introduce multithreading, would be identify whenever a backtracking choice could be made, and spin those off as separate threads (with copy data context).  Then accept the first thread to finish with success.  The obvious place for that would be the second loop in the `solveSudoku9x9(..)` method.

Comment: i understand how you explained how the multithreading process but the problem is that there are a lot of backtrack calls to create enough threads to accommodate them any idea of how to limit thread creation to a max of hardware concurrency? @RBarryYoung

Comment: Limit new thread creation to only the first or second level of recursion.